# Chance of extinction

Tags: probability

In minecraft, after chopping down a tree the leaf blocks have a 1/20 chance of dropping a sapling after they decay. Model this simpler and suggest that the trees give between 0 and 3 (inclusive, evenly distributed) saplings after being chopped down, and each of these saplings have a 100% chance of growing into a new tree.

Eventually, after chopping down a tree it would fail to give us a sapling. If we were to chop down sets of 10 trees, eventually we would find a set of 10 trees which would fail to give us a sapling (less likely). And If we were to chop down sets of 100 trees, we would get to a set which fails to give us even 1 sapling (very unlikely).

We can say the same for any set of "n" trees, no matter the size of "n", given enough time we would be able to chop down a set of "n" trees which would give us no saplings.

My question is, given an arbitrarily large number of starting trees, and the trees giving uniformly distributed 0, 1, 2, or 3 saplings, which can each be planted to make a new tree. If we were to cut down the trees and continue to grow all saplings that are given from these, are we guaranteed to eventually end up with no saplings and no trees? Or is there a chance that the number of trees grows faster than (ahem, I word this badly) probability can catch up with us?

An open question, looking for and expecting discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly standard setup for an extinction problem. Since the expected number of saplings produced by one tree is $\frac{3}{2}$, which is greater than $1$, the probability of extinction is less than $1$.

Suppose we start with one tree. Let $q$ be the probability that this population will eventually become extinct. There are four ways for the population to become extinct:

1. The first tree drops no saplings. This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.
2. The first tree drops one sapling, and that population becomes extinct. This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}q$.
3. The first tree drops two saplings, and the resulting population becomes extinct. This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}q^2$, because we must first have the two-saplings event and then for both of those saplings independently, the population consisting of that sapling and its descendents must become extinct.
4. The first tree drops three saplings, and the resulting population becomes extinct. This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}q^3$, because in this case there are three populations (a sapling and all its descendents) to independently become extinct.

The probability of eventual extinction for a population starting with a single tree is therefore

$$q = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}q + \frac{1}{4}q^2 + \frac{1}{4}q^3.$$

This is a cubic equation in $q$. It has roots at $q = 1$, at $q = \sqrt{2} - 1$, and at $q = -1 - \sqrt{2}$.  According to a well-known result (try a web search for "extinction probability"), the extinction probability is the smallest positive real root, that is, $q = \sqrt{2} - 1$, approximately $0.414$.

If you already have $n$ trees at a given time, the probability of extinction is $q^n$, which is a very small probability when $n = 100$. It's fairly small even when $n = 10$.

Comment: Fascinating, thank you!

Comment: The logic used is wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

If each cutdown tree drops 0, to 3 saplings, with a uniform distribution then the  probability of $n$ trees dropping no saplings is $(0.25)^n$.  Further, the expected replacement rate is $1.5$ new trees per tree cutdown.

It's possible that the trees will go extinct, but for an arbitarily large number, it is not very likely.